# Integrating UDP server in eclipse rcp

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to make a tool that monitors a couple of tcp and udp ports which will then be visualized in different views in an eclipse rcp application.

How should one go about doing this?

I have some trouble figuring out how to attach the TCP and UDP servers to the eclipse framework so that multiple views can listen on them and handle the information accordingly.

Comment: I have now made a solution with a sourceprovider as a singelton, and with that can get the instance and thus can add a listener from the different views.

I am not really satisfied with the solution, it would be better if it could be solvable within the eclipse rcp.

Answer (score 0):

Each view can register itself as a listener to your network monitor using one of these methods:

1. Accessing directly network monitor singleton instance (like you've done):

   NetworkMonitor.getInstance().addMonitorListener(this)
2. Make an OSGI service from your network monitor, then access it from your view using:

   nmServiceTracker = new ServiceTracker(bundleContext, NetworkMonitor.class.getName(), null);
   nmServiceTracker.open();
   ((NetworkMonitor) debugTracker.getServiceReference()).addMonitorListener(this)

   See simple OSGI service [tutorial](http://java.dzone.com/articles/simple-osgi-service) for more info.
3. Create extension point for "Network Monitor Listeners". For more on creating extension points, refer to this [great article](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseExtensionPoint/article.html).